# How to add WordPress Divi Theme localization?

Tags: wordpress, search, localization, multisite, divi-theme

We're having trouble getting the localization to work on our WordPress site.

Our setup is as follows:

- WordPress 4.0.1
- Multi Site enabled
- Divi Theme 2.1.4 (wanted to add Divi to tags, but Stack Overflow doesn't allow me)
- Language Site 1: US English (en_US)
- Language Site 2: Dutch (nl_NL)

Localization is working in the back-end, both in WordPress itself and the Divi Theme builder. However for example the search placeholder stays English. When I go and hack around in the code I find that I can change it in the header-file. But configuring it in the language file (both of WordPress itself and the Divi Language file) does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Without having access to this particular theme's codebase, it's difficult to know exactly what is going on.

But, in general, if a text string is to be localizable, it needs to show up in the template, or the plugin, or WordPress core as

```
__( 'Search by typing here...', 'divi' )
```

instead of

```
'Search by typing here....'
```

This explains it. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/  It mentions plugins, but themes work the same.

If this theme implements the search placeholder, you may have discovered a defect in the theme. You can ask the developer to repair it, or you can make a child theme and repair it yourself. The developer will probably be happy to hear about your bug fix.

In a comment, you mentioned that there's a source code line saying:

```
esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'Divi' ),
```

If you look in the Divi plugin's source code directory, you will probably find a subdirectory called `languages`.  Look in there for a `nl-nl.po` file, or perhaps a `Divi.pot` file containing the strings to be localized.

In there you will, hopefully, find some lines that look like this:

```
msgctxt "placeholder"
msgid "esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;"
msgstr ""
```

If you can fill in the `msgstr` string with the words you need (sorry, I don't know the Dutch language) then you can create or update your .mo file with [poedit](http://poedit.sourceforge.net/).

But many sites use a core-embedded Search widget to display the search box.  Is it possible you're using a plugin of some kind to provide a custom search?

Comment: It shows up like this: esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'Divi' )
I can replace it with a string and then it works, but of course that is ugly and there's a ton of reasons why we don't want that. That's why I'm trying to fix it the nice way ;)

I'm going to hack around and see what happens.

Comment: OK. As said, I hacked around and when I remove the context-param (So above is: esc_attr_x('Search &hellip;','placeholder'), things do work! Am I doing something wrong when placing the nl_NL files in the Divi/lang folder next to the other language files and noting else?

Comment: As far as your edit goes: I do get what you are saying and indeed that is what I found looking at the source code.